# What is a good open source framework to generate ASP.NET form-based editing of an XML file?

Tags: asp.net, xml, editor

I'm currently pondering my options for the following problem:

I have a (relatively) simple but often changing configuration file for my application which I want users to be able to edit and change without have to "understand" xml. I do not want them to have know anything about encoding or understand that they have to close every node they opened. Here is an example of a section in the configuration file (defining facets for some arbitrary search engine):

```
   <section name="facets">
      <facet type="format" label="Format" max="4"/>
      <facet type="marcfields" Label="Author" max="5">
         <mfield name="df100" subfields="abcdjq"/>
      </facet>
      <facet type="language" max="4"/>
      <facet type="pubdate" max="6" submax="8"/> 
   </section>
```

Editing this section, user should should be able to re-order the facets, delete facets, configure existing facets or add new ones. So far so good, but the xml is not completely free form and comes with a couple of restriction/structure:

- Facets come from a pre-defined set of
  types (forkamt, marcields, language &
  pubdate above), so when people choose
  to add a new one, they need to be
  able to choose a type.
- Each facet type comes with "parameters" - some common for all types some specific. For example in the above XML, one can edit the label & max attribute for each facet. For the "marcfields"facet, one can add sub-nodes (with two editable attributes). For the"pubdate" facet, one can edit the submax attribute.

I am looking for a way to take my configuration file and make it editable in ASP.NET web environment. All of this would be fine to program, but I except the configuration file to change often and I don't want to have to recode my site for every change. Therefore I'm looking for an open source frame work which can:

- Take an XML file with a known structure and constraint (via an XML schema or anything else).
- Generate a ASP.NET based editing environment , allowing people to safely manipulate the xml file.
- Be very friendly where people make mistakes.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

How about creating an HTML form using an XSL Transform of the XML file? This way, you can surface the parameters into form fields. Using JQuery, you would even be able to offer re-ordering and the like.

A framework may be a little heavy for this task.